# How do I fix a bad /etc/fstab if the hard disk read-only?

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, read-only

I had created a bootable hackintosh usb stick but I found that I had a problem that could be solved by renaming a file or editing another. But the usb stick was read only and, in a moment of stupidity, I became root and edited `/etc/fstab` so that:

```
error=remount-ro
```

under `dev/sda5` became:

```
error =remount-rw
```

As a result, when I rebooted the pc, it refused to boot. The drive is now mounted read-only and, as a result, I cannot change the rw back to ro. Can anyone help me change etc/fstab back and maybe help me edit the file on the bootable usb?

Answer (score 7):

I mounted the partition using `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda5 /`
in the Ubuntu recovery terminal and then edited the file to fix the problem. I restarted the computer and that fixed it.

Comment: If something is already mounted, it's enough to specify either the device or image file to mount (`/dev/sda5`) or the mount point directory (`/`). Passing both as argument seems not to hurt, but is superfluous.